# socket io and mqtt nodejs duplicate entry

Tags: node.js, socket.io, mqtt

I am using mqttjs and socketio on my nodejs backend.
I am using angular as my frontend framework.

On my frontend there are 3 routes.
All requires socket connection for real time data.
So on ngOnInit i run client side socket io connection code and on ngOnDestroy I will run socket disconnect as well.

And in my server side code (index.js) there are mainly 3 actions that is happening.

```
const io = require('socket.io')(server)
mqtt.createConnection();
mqtt.mqttSubscriptions(io);
mqtt.mqttMessages(io);
```

These are the mqtt methods:

```
const createConnection = () => {
    let options = {
        protocol: 'mqtt',
        clientId: process.env.MQTT_CLIENT_ID,
        username: process.env.MQTT_USERNAME,
        password: process.env.MQTT_PASSWORD,
    };
    client = mqtt.connect(process.env.MQTT_HOST, options);

    client.on('connect', function() {
        winston.info('MQTT connected');
    });

    client.on('error', function(err) {
        winston.error(err);
    });
};

const mqttSubscriptions = io => {   
    winston.info(`Socket connected.`);
        client.subscribe([TOPICS.DATA], function(error, granted) {
            if (error) {
                winston.error(error);
            }

            winston.info('Topics: ', granted);
    }); 
};

const mqttMessages = io => {
    io.sockets.on('connection', socket => {
     winston.info(`Socket connected.`);
     client.on('message', function(topic, message) {
        let payload = JSON.parse(message.toString());
        winston.info(topic);
        winston.info(payload.id);
        switch (topic) {
            case TOPICS.DATA:
                dataController.storeData(payload, io);
                break;

            default:
                winston.error('Wrong topic');
                break;
        }
     });
   });
};
```

And on the datacontroller I am running

```
socket.emit()
```

My problem is everytime I navigate to a route and come back the `dataController.storeData` is called multiple times.

That is when I am at route A, and then navigate to route B and then back to A and then to C, the data is multiplied that many times of my route navigation. (In this case 4 times.)

I found that it is socket io and mqtt connection problem, but I don't know how to solve, since I am new to both of these.

Any help?

Comment: Any reason you are using socket.io rather than using MQTT over Websockets and making the subscription from within the page rather than the back end?

Comment: I need to store the incoming mqtt data, and once that passes some condition I need to emit that data accordingly